# Repetead sequential numbers by group

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Let's consider one has the following *dataframe*:

| date | x | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-30 | a | 1 |
| 2021-09-30 | b | 2 |
| 2021-09-30 | c | 3 |
| 2021-12-31 | e | 1 |
| 2021-12-31 | f | 2 |
| 2021-12-31 | g | 3 |
| 2022-03-31 | t | 1 |
| 2022-03-31 | u | 2 |
| 2022-03-31 | z | 3 |

I need to create a new increasing and monotonic ID by the date variable.

For instance, the new *dataframe* should appear as follows:

| date | x | counter | new counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-30 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-09-30 | b | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-09-30 | c | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-12-31 | e | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-12-31 | f | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-12-31 | g | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-03-31 | t | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-03-31 | u | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-03-31 | z | 3 | 3 |

I'm running the R version 3.6.3; in the hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: does `ǹew counter` depend on other columns or is it just based on the row number?

Comment: In your example, f and g have the same new counter. Why?

Comment: @danlooo it depends on date only.

Comment: my fault in typing the table in the question @danlooo . I'm going to the edit the question!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::cur_group_id()` to do the job.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(new_counter = cur_group_id())

# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   date [3]
  date       x     counter new_counter
  <chr>      <chr>   <int>       <int>
1 2021-09-30 a           1           1
2 2021-09-30 b           2           1
3 2021-09-30 c           3           1
4 2021-12-31 e           1           2
5 2021-12-31 f           2           2
6 2022-03-31 g           3           3
7 2022-03-31 t           1           3
8 2022-03-31 u           2           3
9 2022-03-31 z           3           3
```